# wxPython from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, wxpython

I have a wxPython application developed on Linux that I wish to deploy on Windows machines. While most of the things work well on porting there are small (but catastrophic) problems, none of which seem related. Rather than list them all, I'll start with one.

I have an array of images that I read in and place in a GridBagSizer in a Class. Unfortunately, the 'Bind' statement doesn't seem to take effect, and when I double-click on an image 'onSuitDClick' is not called.

```
    suitSizer=SuitDisplay(self, suit

def onSuitDClick(self, event):
  print 'sc'            

class SuitDisplay(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, frame, suit):
  wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame, id=wx.ID_ANY)

  suitSizer=wx.GridBagSizer(1, 13)
  suitList=[]
  for ii in range(0, len(g.CARDS)):
    if g.CARDS[ii]+g.SUITS[suit] in frame.availableCards:
      card=g.CARDS[ii]+g.SUITS[suit]
      suitList.append(card)
  for ii in range(0, len(suitList)):
    card= suitList[ii]  
    image = wx.Bitmap(frame.imageFolder+card+'.png',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToImage()
    img = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, image.ConvertToBitmap(), name=card)
    img.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, frame.onSuitDClick)

    suitSizer.Add(img, pos=(0,cardPos), flag=wx.LEFT, border=border)
  self.SetSizer(suitSizer)
```

Needless to say, this works perfectly in Linux.

Can anyone suggest where I might look for a solution?

Comment: Can't see the problem looking at the code.  A http://wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps would make things easier to test.

Comment: BTW, I assume the indent is correct in your code, above is not correctly indented.  Why do you convert the Bitmap.ConvertToImage and then reconvert it ConvertToBitmap, can't be the cause of the problem, but seems inefficient.

Comment: I agree a sample app would help. But I've created a simple app and that works just as expected

Comment: Sorry about the indentation. Yes, it's correct in the module. ('Class' came out wrong when I pasted)

Comment: Hhm, what is different in the simple app compare to your real code?  One thing I would check is the hierarchy of widgets (use the WIT for that - http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool), i.e. is the parent of the StaticBitmap the same, then the parent of the panel and so on.  If that doesn't help then you need to make your simple app more complex, i.e. get it closer to what the real thing is.

Comment: Thanks Werner. That's solved this one. Some implementations of Python are clearly more forgiving than others

Comment: BTW I ConvertToImage and then ConvertToBitmap because in the app I am resizing. I took it out to simplify the example